# Can I train 2 distinct NNs on 2 distinct GPUs simultaneously?

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, tensorflow

I never had 2 GPUs, but I am going have 2 on one PC soon.

Sometimes I would like to train a model using both cards, to train as fast as possible. However I imagine a situation, where I will want to train two distinct models simultaneously.

Will it be possible using frameworks like Tensorflow or PyTorch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use very simple method. Start two distinct python scripts one with first model and one with second. In TensorFlow you can  explicitly specify device by using `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):`, `with tf.device('/gpu:1'):` etc. For more information look at documentation [TensorFlow Using GPUs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu).